# Rendering fullcalendar.io in polymer a core-animated-pages section

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, polymer, core-elements

I have an app setup using core-animated pages to transition between my section. In one section I am trying to render the fullcalendar plugin (http://fullcalendar.io/). Using the sbg-fullcalendar element to do this: https://github.com/Smorgasbord-Development/sgb-fullcalendar

This works great if i put the element in the first section of my app. The app loads and on the domReady event the calendar renders. However, I want to include in any section and when I do it doesn't render.

I've made updates to sbg-calendar element to listen for the core-animated-pages-transition-end event. The calendar element does catch the event and tries creates a calendar, but it still doesn't render.

Could the rendering issue be because a jQuery selectors don't work in the shadow dom? I'm very new to polymer and unsure about a lot of its inner workings.

Here's my index page.

```
<core-animated-pages id="pages" selected="{{selected}}" transitions="cross-fade fade-slide-up fade-scale" fit>

        <section layout vertical>

            <categories-page class="page" id="categories" cross-fade?="{{largeScreen}}" fade-slide-up?="{{!largeScreen}}" heading="{{heading}}" flex></categories-page>
        </section>

        <section layout vertical>
            <calendar-page  class="page" cross-fade?="{{largeScreen}}" fade-slide-up?="{{!largeScreen}}" heading="{{heading}}" flex></calendar-page>
        </section>
    </core-animated-pages>
```

and Calendar Page:

```
<link rel="import" href="../base-page/base-page.html">
```

```
        <!-- Main -->
        <div main layout vertical>
            <core-header-panel id="headerPanel" mode="seamed" flex>
                <core-toolbar>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" core-drawer-toggle>
                    </paper-icon-button>
                    <div id="title" flex>{{heading}}</div>

                    <paper-menu-button id="menuBtn" noink>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" noink></paper-icon-button>
                        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" halign="right">
                            <core-menu class="menu">
                                <paper-item>Settings</paper-item>
                                <paper-item>Help</paper-item>
                                <paper-item>Feedback</paper-item>
                            </core-menu>
                        </paper-dropdown>
                    </paper-menu-button>

                </core-toolbar>
                <div class="content" style="max-height:1000px;">

                        <sgb-fullcalendar id="calendar" defaultView="month"></sgb-fullcalendar>

                </div>
            </core-header-panel>
        </div>
</template>
<script>
    (function () {
        Polymer({
            willPrepare: function () {
                this.super();

            },
            getUrl: function (idx) {
                console.log(window.location.pathname + '/' + idx);
                return '/subjects/' + idx;
            }              
        });
    })();
</script>
```

I've been using Rob Dodson's contacts app as an example for my app too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've succeded rendering the fullCalendar on one of my section (I also used the core-animated-pages) by using the domReady method. This is how I would do it in your case :

```
<polymer-element name="calendar-page" attributes="Your Attribute">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer("calendar-page",{
        domReady: function() {
          $(this.$.calendar).fullCalendar({
                weekends: false ,
                allDaySlot: false,
                minTime : "06:00:00",
                maxTime : "18:00:00",
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                header: {left:'title', center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month', right:  'today prev,next'},
                googleCalendarApiKey: 'YourApiKey',
                events: {
                    googleCalendarId: 'YourCalendarId',
                },
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    //console.log(calEvent);
                    return false;
                },
            })
        },
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to link the css file from inside of your element. Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! This really helped me get past my issues. Polymer is still a little tricky for me coming from backbone, angular, and jquery space. Your simple implementation really helped. Thank you!

Comment: If you are using Polymer 1.x, domReady is not available anymore. Read here how to replace it: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#domready